# How tell an other component of changement state of redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two components reactjs , I create an state redux to handle this state from two components .

```
  `appcomponent.js 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//reducer
export function get_user(state=[], action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_USER':
      return [
        {user:action.user}
      ];
      default:
      return state;
  }
     }  
class appcomponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Users:[]};
        //this.addUser=this.addUser.bind(this);
        this.onFormSubmit=this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.get=this.get.bind(this);
      }
get(){
    console.log(this.props.r);
}
onFormSubmit() {
  this.props.send('user');
}
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
   <br /><br /><br />
     <button onClick={this.onFormSubmit}>redux</button><br /><br /><br /><br />
     <button onClick={this.get}>REDUX</button>
    </div>
  )}
}
// action
export function addUser(user) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_USER',
    user,
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch)  {
  return {
    send: user => dispatch(addUser(user))
  };
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return  { r:state};

};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(appcomponent);
```

In this component when I click "redux" button then onclick "REDUX" button I get the state changed. 
In the other component I have this code :

```
 class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }
render() {
    return (
<div><h1>{this.props.user}</h1></div>
)
}}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return  { user: state[0].user};//.user
};
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch)  {
  return {
    get: user => dispatch(addUser('username'))
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

In the last component always I get the initial state created in index.js

```
var store = createStore(get_user,[{user:'hhhh'}]);
ReactDOM.render( <Provider store={store}>
```

Please who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call createStore() once, preferably near the top of your component tree not in each component.

Assuming you wrap your app in a Provider (from redux) you'll have access to redux's central State via the mapStateToProps function (where you can assign state elements to a particular components props):

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    user: usersReducer,
    otherThings: otherThingsReducer
  })
)

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MainAppComponentOrRouter/>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
```

And then in a component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    otherThings: state.otherThings
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I delete createstore from the second component , then I added the const mapstateToprops in the same component but the same problem . It seems I did some error .

Comment: Always I get the initial state in the second components despite I changed it from the first component!!!

Answer (score 0):

in the first component try use the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//reducer
export function get_user(state={user:[]}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_USER':
      return {
        ...state,
        user:action.user
      }

      default:
      return state;
  }
     }  
class appcomponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Users:[]};
        //this.addUser=this.addUser.bind(this);
        this.onFormSubmit=this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.get=this.get.bind(this);
      }
get(){
    console.log(this.props.r);
}
onFormSubmit() {
  this.props.send('user');
}
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
   <br /><br /><br />
     <button onClick={this.onFormSubmit}>redux</button><br /><br /><br /><br />
     <button onClick={this.get}>REDUX</button>
    </div>
  )}
}
// action
export function addUser(user) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_USER',
    user,
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch)  {
  return {
    send: user => dispatch(addUser(user))
  };
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return  { r:state};

};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(appcomponent);
```

and on the second component use the following code

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }
render() {
    return (
<div><h1>{this.props.user}</h1></div>
)
}}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return  { user: state.user};//.user
};
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch)  {
  return {
    get: user => dispatch(addUser('username'))
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I want to have always one user in state , I want the reducer return just the action.user.

Comment: okay, then just replace this `user:[...state.user, action.user]` to this `user: action.user` on the reducer

Comment: And `...state` I don't remove it ?

Comment: no keep it , it should return `{...state, user:action.user}`

Comment: with `...state` it will add the new user not chnage it with the new , or no ?

Comment: no, it will not add new user, use this to keep your state with current data if you put another data from different reducer, check in `user` if it change with new user or add new user every time ?

Comment: In this state I want always have only one user , so each time when I dispatch new user it will replace the old user by this new user without keep the current user.

Comment: are you tried that code on my answer, with change the reducer to `{...state, user:action.user}`

Comment: Yes but I lost all the results , now I can't change the state even by the first component .

Comment: return your first component to the old code, then show me your redux state after dispatch the action

Comment: As you seen in my initial state I have `hhhh` , so in starting I have in two components this state. Now onclick `redux` button the state in the `appcomponent` change but in the `App` component always return the initial state.

Comment: There is my routes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327935/how-use-redux-state-with-routes-react-router/47343775#47343775