# How use redux state with routes react-router?

Tags: react-router, react-redux

I created my routes

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/redux" component={redux} />
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

My problem is when I dispatch an action from redux component , the props changed in the `/redux` route but in the `/` always the initial state. Please who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `react-router-redux` (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) to synchronise `redux` store with `react-router`.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

// Add router reducer to your store on the `routing` key
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  })
)
// Create enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

...

<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/redux" component={redux} />
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

Comment: I must just add this code or I must edit also my reducer ?

Comment: Sorry, also you need to add router reducer to your store. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have only one reducer called . I did this
` const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    myreducer,
    routing: routerReducer
  })` , I get an error that reducer undefined :(
)

Comment: here my full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290038/how-tell-an-other-component-of-changement-state-of-redux/47338041?noredirect=1#comment81629781_47338041

Comment: Please, double check that you imported `react-router-redux` properly, and pass right data to `combineReducers` method. `combineReducers` method expected an object as argument.

Comment: All you need is [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux). They also have [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/tree/master/examples/basic).